# How to change color only of footers in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, footers, footnote

I have this Word document with 700+ pages. Most of the text is in black, some of it is in red (and it should remain red). The same happens with the footers, some of them are in black, some of them are in red, but all of the footers must be in color black.

I checked styles but the person who created the document didn't use any, all of the text, titles, normal text, footers, etc use the 'Mormal' style.

Is there any way of change the color only of all the footers to black?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the text always the same, or does it differ?
I am not aware you can search/select all footers.

It is possible to search for a specific layout (eventually combined with specific text): Go to find, open advanced find, click the 'more' button and then at the bottomleft you have a dropdown to search based on layout.
In the search-replace dialog you can choose the layout of what you search and replace it with another layout (by clicking the field for tekst to search)

In the case every single footer is completely different you can only use the go-to function (ctrl-g) to navigate to each and every section.  There you change the layout of the first footer and go to the next section.

[image: image from wiley.com]

Comment: All footnotes are different! But you gave an idea, I've just used the find and replace command, and searched for the exact format of the footnotes (Times New Roman, size 10, color: Red) and in 'replace' I change the red color for black color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using the 'Find and Replace' command.

With the cursor in the the 'Find what' field, went to 'Format' and set the format of the footnotes I wanted to change, in this case: Times New Roman, size 10, color Red.

[image]

[image]

Then placed the cursor in the 'Replace with' field, went to 'Format' and set the desired format, in this case: Times New Roman, size 10, color Black.

[image]

[image]

The clicked 'Replace All' and DONE!

[image]